# Boot-loader to boot to an encrypted partition

Tags: security, boot, grub-legacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux boot loaders supporting full disk encryption?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30120/linux-boot-loaders-supporting-full-disk-encryption)

I am looking for a Boot-loader which is smart enough to boot from an Encrypted partition. I want to place the kernel and initramfs/initrd in an encrypted boot partition.

I use grub-legacy but it can not find the kernel on such a boot partition.

Are there any boot-loaders with such an ability?

Comment: Here is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179365/linux-boot-loaders-supporting-full-disk-encryption

Answer (score 0):

Try `grub2`. It should support booting from an encrypted partition.

Comment: As per the [link]http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html , grub can not read the files from the encrypted Partition.