# Encrypting hard drive containing the MBR with Veracrypt

Tags: linux, encryption, luks, mbr, veracrypt

I have three hard drives in my laptop: /dev/sdc (an mSATA drive) is where the system is installed and is completely encrypted with LUKS. /dev/sdb (for media/text files - the majority of /home) was encrypted with Veracrypt and decrypted and mounted on boot via crypttab and fstab.

During the installation (Manjaro calamares installer) I installed the MBR on /dev/sda as I previously had problems with trying to boot from the other hard drives. When I start the machine it reads the MBR from /dev/sda, I enter my password, it decrypts /dev/sdc and boots into Manjaro.

Currently /dev/sda is unencrypted but I would like to encrypt it via Veracrypt and decrypt/mount on boot like I do already with /dev/sdb. However, I am worried that by fully encrypting this drive I will not be able to boot into the system as this HDD contains the MBR.

Could someone tell me if the encryption affects the reading of the MBR at all or will encrypting the drive cause no problems? The drive also has the "/boot" flag.

Thank you

Comment: [possibly related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30120/linux-boot-loaders-supporting-full-disk-encryption)

Comment: Thank you! I've read the question before and I *assume* that due to the question being asked then the MBR never gets encrypted from FDE. However, I wouldn't mind someone confirming this to be the case.

Comment: My experience is always "on-the-job" ...  I'll be glad to run a test after Jan 2nd... I'll bookmark and give it a try if no one else gets to it first.

Comment: If Veracrypt works with loop files, you could make create a "test drive" with a MBR, then see exactly what veracrypt does